# Barcode scanner for book site

Tags: php, barcode

I'm creating a social networking site for books (like Goodreads) and I'd like to include a feature whereby a user can scan the barcode of a book using the webcam and get information about that book.

The functionality for finding the information is already complete. I just need to know how to make the webcam read the ISBN and output it as a string, which I can then feed into my script which fetches the information. At the moment this is just done by filling in a form with the IBSN.

My website is built using PHP.

I can't seem to find a working solution online.

Any ideas of how I could go about implementing this?

Comment: [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) - About which types of barcodes are you asking specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Idea would be to use Flash barcode scanner. I've seen flash software that recognizes gestures and so on, so barcode shouldn't be that hard.

Here you can see it implemented: http://gurulib.wordpress.com/2007/12/28/a-flash-based-webcam-barcode-reader/